# How is the recursive function working which seems to be 'infinite recursive'?

Tags: c, recursion

This is the related part of a program taken from web.

```
int N, cont[37];

void solve(int n, int sum) {
    if (n == N/2) {
        ++cont[sum];
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) solve(n+1, sum+i);
    }
}

int main() {
    N = 4;
    solve(0, 0);
    .....
    return 0;
}
```

This program has been taken from web. The recursive function is working nicely, but it seems to me to be an infinite recursive. Can anyone define the process of the function?

Comment: Why don't you use a *debugger* and single-step through that code? You would easily understand yourself how it works.

Answer (score 3):

For every call to `solve` with `n` there are two possibilities:

1. `n == N/2` (or `n == 2` in this case). There are no recursive calls, so execution returns.
2. There are 10 calls made with `n+1`.

As long as the initial `n` is below `N/2`, every sequence of calls will go up until `n` reaches `N/2`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at refactored version of this function:

```
void solve(int n, int sum)
{
  if (n == N/2)
    ++cont[sum]; //function exits without recursive call
  else
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      solve(n+1,sum+1); //recursive call
  }
}
```

So recursive ends at solve(N/2, ...) call

Comment: You mean when the function will reach at `++cont[sum]` , the function will exit without being back to the return address(i mean being back and increasing value of  `i` and then make another call)?

Comment: yes. Function solve call itself recursively only if argument `n` less than constant `N/2`. So there are no _infinite recursive_

Comment: sorry but now i think, solve could call itself even if `n> const N/2` as the `else` statements will be executed every time `n != N/2`. Isn't it?

Comment: yep. You are right. `solve` can fall into endless recursive if first called with `n` greater than `N/2`. But original invocation `solve(0,0)` isn't that case. In any case this function looks weird and unsafe, so i suggest to rewrite it.